libtomcrypt ecc_ansi_x963_import allocates memory?
I am working with libtomcrypt and have a memory leak in my program. I believe it is around the use of ecc_ansi_x963_import from libtomcrypt.
Does ecc_ansi_x963_import allocate memory? The docs (version 1.18.2 as of the time of this post) only say that "This function will free any allocated memory upon error" which implies that it allocates memory.
If it does allocate, should I use ecc_free on my ecc_key structure that I pass to exx_ansi_x963_import? The docs only say that it is used to free memory allocated by "ecc_make_key(), ecc_make_key_ex(), ecc_import(), or ecc_import_ex()" and does not make mention of ecc_ansi_x963_import or ecc_ansi_x963_import_ex.
